# Unable to convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a function (`varchar`) to `date`, but get the below error message.

**Error**

> Failed to convert date and / or time from string.

**Script**

```
DECLARE @MyDate date

SET @MyDate = CONVERT(date, dbo.GETMINDATE(0123), 103)

SELECT @MyDate
```

The function itself returns a `varchar` date like so - `'01 Apr 2010 08:00:00.000'`.

The SQL Server host is in French settings, so perhaps it's a regional setting issue.

Comment: don't pass dates around as strings, use DATETIME2 or DATE

Comment: When I change DECLARE @MyDate date to Datetime2, or datetime, I get the same error message.

Comment: the function should return the correct datatype. Not a string `01 Apr 2010 08:00:00:000` isn't a valid format in any language. Usually there is a decimal point after the seconds not a colon

Comment: `The function itself returns a varchar date like so` change the function to return a `date` or `datetime`. The problem is in that function. For more help, you'll have to post that function's code

Comment: The function "dbo.GETMINDATE(0123)" returns other information other than dates, so I can't amend it unfortunately. Agreed it's not good practice, but it's in use already in the system, and it's not something I can change right now. What's strange is that this exact same script and function return fine locally on a UK SQL Server.

Comment: Ummm....that function is a scalar function so it isn't returning other data. Unless you mean it has some crazy logic so that it might return a date as a string or some other string depending on the input parameter. The error you are facing is almost certainly because of language differences with date literals. Yet another argument for why you should use the proper datatype.

Comment: *"dbo.GETMINDATE(0123)" returns other information other than dates* - that's **definitely** a blatant violation of the *Principle of Least Surprise*! If the function is **called** `GetMinDate` - I would **always** expect to get back a **DATE** - and not anything else - ***EVER***......

Comment: If you are stuck with this and can't change this then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 is what you need

Comment: MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql suggests you use `113` instead of `103`. but replace the `.` with a `:` first.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all. The function can indeed bring back a mixture of results from a table we have - this could be dates or text ( I just named it getMinDate for ease of use here). Yes, it's bad design and bad practice, I did not create it, it was created long before my time and have only been made aware of it now because of this error, which I will now fix. The reason it's happening on this particular DB is down to French language settings as Smor pointed out. Gonna be fun finding all places where this may be causing problems!

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck with this and can't change this to fix the function to return the correct datatype then you can use `PARSE` to specify a static culture (so completely unaffected by the locale of the server and the default settings of its users).

```
SELECT PARSE('01 Apr 2010 08:00:00.000' AS date USING 'en-US')
```

Obviously replace the string literal with your function call. As you are casting to `date` in the question I have used the same, this will truncate the time portion.

Use `datetime` or `datetime2` if that was not the intention.

Comment: Thanks, will test this tomorrow, might be helpful for fixing other instances of this issue!

Answer (score 0):

So you guessed that it might be a regional or language setting. You guessed correctly. Tibor discusses all facets of the datetime datatype [here](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes). Specifically he mentions that the format you use (with the month abbreviation) depends on the language setting in use at runtime. Here is an [fiddle to demonstrate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e4c601ba814aeabdaf84201ffe77d98).

So how should you fix this? Well, you could force everyone else in the world (every user in your database) to use one of the english language settings. Somehow I don't think that will go over well in the real world. Seems a team meeting might be needed to determine an appropriate path forward. This is a tough lesson to learn about software design.

Comment: It's not necessary to convert the planet to English date formats as `PARSE` accepts a culture and can deal with that format fine

Comment: Wow, was thinking it language settings was a long shot. The link you sent me is exactly what's happening over here (French language too!). Thanks for this. Quick question - are there any repercussions or issues with changing a language (say from French to English)? If not, then the customer may not mind, as it was previously in English on their older server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an experiment

```
--this returns a value
set language english;
select CAST('01 Apr 2010 08:00:00.000' as date);

--this works
set language french;
select CAST('01 Avr 2010 08:00:00.000' as date);

--this errors out 
set language french;
select CAST('01 Apr 2010 08:00:00.000' as date);
```

so you can possibly translate the value, according to local settings (which you can vary in the scope of a query).